# parent and set localpositions and rotation from gameobjects to a specific local location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform, parent

What i'm trying to do is, i have a player say a lion, and there are enemies, other animals.

What i want is the player to grab the enemy when they die and put the neck in his mouth, so he can take them with him.

All enemy animals have a localposition for the neck but they are all different.

What i have is this:

```
    Enemy1.SetParent(DragMouth.transform);
    Enemy1.gameObject.transform.position = Enemy1.GetComponentInChildren<Neck>().transform.TransformPoint(0,0,0);
    Enemy1.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

This kinda works but because all animals have different positions it doesn't work good.

What would be the correct way to set the neck of the enemies to the "Dragmouth" position?

I'm using unity btw.

Comment: So, your DragMouth (Lion) gameobject will grab the necks of all enemies at once?

Comment: No just from 1 enemy at a time, it's like the player kills an enemy and then gets the option to grab him in his mouth and move him to some other position.

Comment: hmmm..... Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script to the animals that knows the offset from their own position to the position of their neck. Then when the enemy tries to grab the target you just substract that offset to the base mouth position to keep them in the correct position.
So something like (**NOTE The example code will only work without rotation adjustments, you'll have to do some more calculations to make it work with rotations :)**):

```
public class Lion : Monobehaviour 
{
    public Vector3 offsetToMouth
    {
        get {
            return mouthObject.localPosition;           
        }
    }

    //Make a child object that is on the mouth position
    //Reference to this object through unity inspector
    public Transform mouthObject;

    //The target that is currently in lions mouth
    private Target currentTarget;


    void Update() 
    {
        var mouthPosition = transform.position + offsetToMouth;
        var newPosition = mouthPosition - currentTarget.offsetToNeck;
        currentTarget.gameObject.transform.position = newPosition;
    }   
}

public class Target : Monobehaviour
{
    public Vector3 offsetToNeck 
    {
        get {
            return neckObject.localPosition;            
        }
    }

    //Make a child object that is on the neck position
    //Reference to this object through unity inspector
    public Transform neckObject;
}
```